# ngFor with nested selects

Tags: angular, html-select, ngfor

How can I use `ngFor` correctly using a nested select?
My current code is this:

```js
<tr *ngFor="let role of user.roles">
  <td>{{role.permissionId}}
     <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="role.permissionId" name="permissions">                       
        <option *ngFor="let permission of permissions" [ngValue]="permission.key">{{permission.value}}
        </option>                        
     </select>    
  </td>                                     
</tr>
```

The select is filled corectly with all options but the value selected dont correspond to the object(role). When I push a new element to the array all the dropdowns take the same value.

Comment: Do `role.permissionId` and `permission.key` hold the same values (same object instance if they are not primitive values)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the solution is to write `*ngFor="let permission of role.permissions"` - if `permissons` is a property of a `role` object.